# How to save tag html to variable using Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex

I have function `<?php the_content(); ?>` wihch generate html tag:

```
<p>
 <a href="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-82" title="page1-img2" src="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" width="219" height="124" />
 </a>
</p>
```

I am try to extract the `<img.**./>` but I don't sucsses.

somthing like:

```
//$String =
<p>
 <a href="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg">
  <img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-82" title="page1-img2" src="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" width="219" height="124" />
 </a>
</p> 

$String = "the_content()";

$pattern = '/^<img/.*/$/>/';//Take string wich start with "<img" and all between and End in "/>"
preg_match($pattern, substr($subject,3), $StrImg, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $StrImg[0];
output
//<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-82" title="page1-img2" src="http://127.0.0.1/www/www1/wordpress/wordpressEng/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/page1-img2.jpg" alt="" width="219" height="124" />
```

How can I set to variable `$StrImg` the complete img tag ?

Many thanks.

Comment: Enable error_reporting. Remove the redundant forward slashes, which are your delimiter, then. Also there are easier ways to extract snippets from HTML; DOM frontends are less efficient, but if you are this unversed with regex, often preferrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to get the src attributes for all the images in you post. There are easier ways:

```
$images = get_posts(array(
            'post_parent' => $post->ID,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image'
        ))

        foreach( $images as $image ) {
            $image_url[] = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, full );

        }
```